# Scheduled task Error Log on as a batch job

Tags: scheduled-tasks, windows-server-2019

I have the following problem: I am trying to run a PowerShell script as a scheduled task on a Windows Server 2019 Standard.
In order to do that, I wanted to use a dedicated user first. I knew that running a scheduled task may require the user right "Log on as a batch job". So I added the user to the Backup-Operators group, since that group has the right by default. I checked this via PowerShell on the server => the user was successfully added to the group and therefore also has the right.

However, when I now want to create the scheduled task, I always get the following error:

> This task requires that the specified user account has the "Log on as
> batch job" right.

To be on the safe side, and the error ist not due to a missing user right, I then tried to run the task as administrator. This user also has the right "Log on as batch job" by default. But also here the same error message appears. If I then try to start the task anyway I get the following error:

Task scheduling could not start the task "[My task]" for the user "[Administrator]". Additional data: Error value: 2147943785

According to my research, the error code only says that the Log on as batch job right is required.

Scheduled task settings:

- Run regardless of user logon
- Run with highest privileges

what I have already tried:

- When I manually run the script via PS session on the server, everything works fine. Both with the dedicated user and as administrator.
- I also tried a simple script, which only reads the service, but the same error message appears.
- Also with a .bat file the same error occurs
- On my local PC the script works without problems, both with the dedicated user and as administrator (they are in the same domain).

Thanks in advance

Comment: have the same problem, did you figure this out?